# Python PEP 8 and vertical distance for function definitions

Tags: python, function, pep8

I can't find if PEP 8 talks about *vertical distance* of dependent functions (this is covered in the *Clean Code* book, *Chapter 5: Formatting*, section *Vertical Formatting* > *Vertical Distance*) and I want to know what the Python rules are for the order of function definitions.

After reading the Clean Code book, I'll create a class that defines the methods in the same order as they are used, like this:

```py
class A:
    def main(self):
        self._function_1()
        self._function_2()
        self._function_3()

    def _function_1(self):
        print("Hi 1!")

    def _function_2(self):
        print("Hi 2!")

    def _function_3(self):
        print("Hi 3!")
```

But maybe PEP 8 specifies something different, because I see some scripts set the definition of the last used method first. They modify the above example as:

```py
class A:
    def main(self):
        self._function_1()
        self._function_2()
        self._function_3()

    def _function_3(self):
        print("Hi 3!")

    def _function_2(self):
        print("Hi 2!")

    def _function_1(self):
        print("Hi 1!")
```

I've also heard that in Python the order of functions varies depending on whether they are in a class or not.

If you can give me information about it, I will be very grateful.

Thanks!

EDIT. A brief clarification, as shown in the examples in the question, I refer to *vertical distance* as how close the definition of a method is to its use, with no other method definitions in between.

Comment: I doubt there's any standard for the order of methods, except I'd expect `__init__` to be first.

Comment: I just checked PEP-8, it doesn't say anything about the order of methods. I'm not sure what you mean by "vertical distance".

Comment: Your question assumes that methods are only used from one place, otherwise the concept of "last used" makes no sense. But that's not likely to be common.

Comment: Thanks Barman.

I use "vertical distance" to follow the term used in the Clean Code book. It means being vertically close, without other code between them (as possible). The text of the book says: "Dependent Functions. If one function calls another, they should be vertically close,
and the caller should be above the callee, if at all possible".

Comment: Again, that assumes that the functions are only used together. Most functions are intended for more general use, not just from a single dependent function.

Comment: PEP 8 is agnostic about these considerations, AFAIK

Comment: There does not seem tooling available to enforce "vertical distance" or "step down rule". And if there is no tooling to enforce it, the order will probably be lost when working with multiple persons. If you are alone you can sort as you like (Allphabetical order is already provided by structure view of PyCharm). Also see related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76611154/how-to-automatically-sort-functions-in-classes-by-their-usage

Comment: In a plain python script, a function definition has to be located before its usage. Usually, there is an expression at the end of the file, jumping to the top of the file where a main function is located. With this "workaround" the functions can be put in wanted order, reading them from top to bottom, as in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in PEP 8 it's near the top of the style guide.

### Blank Lines

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank
> lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank
> line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of
> related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of
> related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
>
> Python accepts the control-L (i.e. ^L) form feed character as
> whitespace; many tools treat these characters as page separators, so
> you may use them to separate pages of related sections of your file.
> Note, some editors and web-based code viewers may not recognize
> control-L as a form feed and will show another glyph in its place.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your reply. I think you have confused *vertical distance* with blank lines, I've just updated the question with a brief clarification to avoid future misunderstandings. Despite that, your answer helped me to see that I add a blank line after the class names, I've just removed these unneeded blank lines.